# Passing two variables from dropdownmenu in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to reload my page (PHP) on changing value from the dropdownmenu and passing the value of selected item as a variable alongwith one another variable to the page. I have tried following -

```
<select name="application" onChange=Refresh(this.value,$query)" \>
<option>Any Application</option>
<option>ChIP</option>
<option>Enzyme Immunoassay</option>
<option>ELISA</option>
<option>Flow Cytometry</option>
<option>FACS</option>
</select>
```

The Refresh function is:

```
function Refresh(id,gene){
location.href="getnet.php?app=" + id + "&query=" + gene;
}
```

And i am receiving variables as:

```
$query = $_POST['gene'];
$app = $_POST['application'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use form `submit()` method in `onchange` event of the dropdown and hidden field for second parameter, for example:

```
<form name="myForm" method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <select name="first" onChange="document.myForm.submit();">
    <option value="1">Value 1
    <option value="2">Value 2
    <option value="3">Value 3
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="second" value="second parameter value"/>
</form>
```

On the server side you can get your variables in `$_GET` supperglobal array like:
`$_GET['first']` - it's value from dropdown element and `$_GET['second']` - second hidden param.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write js function for dropdown onchange event. Below is sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function reload_url(val){
    window.location.href = 'some_php_file.php?new_var='.val;
 }
 </script>

 <select name="my_Sel" onchange="reload_url(this.value);">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: If you notice, i have to pass one other variable alongwith that.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying a form submit onChange?

```
<form name="form" action="url" method="get">
    <select name="application" onChange="this.form.submit();" > 
        <option>Any Application</option> 
        <option>ChIP</option> 
        <option>Enzyme Immunoassay</option> 
        <option>ELISA</option> 
        <option>Flow Cytometry</option> 
        <option>FACS</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="gene" value="variable" />
</form>
```